# Opengl: Transparency and Depth Test Problems

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to render two different objects using normal glColor4f(), The scene contains a huge plane with evenly subdivided surface and a simple cube in the center which is smaller than the plane and is divided in half by the plane.

Problem 1: When I try to turn the view around, the cube seems to be completely above the plane. It looks just like an Escher figure.How to fix depth testing properly?

Problem2: the small cube is supposed to be transparent and see through type, but transparency isn't working.

My initialization method.

```
void GWidget::initializeGL()
{
    setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer|QGL::DepthBuffer|QGL::Rgba|QGL::DepthBuffer));


    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_SRC_ALPHA);

    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);

    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslatef(0,0,-1);
        glClearColor(0.4,0.5,0.4,0);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glPushMatrix();
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

        glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

//        glScalef(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);

}
```

Resizing method:

```
void GWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height );
     glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
     glLoadIdentity();

     glOrtho ( -width,width,-height,height, 0.0, 200.0 );
     glPushMatrix();

     glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
     glLoadIdentity();
     glTranslatef(0,0,-3);
     glScalef(0.7,0.7,0.7);
     glPushMatrix();
     glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Draw Method for ObjectX class:(The Plane)

```
void ObjectX::GDraw(int i)
{
    qint32 count,iter;
    MeshX *dmesh;
    VertX *dvert;
    EdgeX *dedge;
    FaceX *dface;

    QList<VertX* > *vlist;


    dmesh=this->Meshes[i];
    vlist=dmesh->getVList();

     iter=0;
     int a,b;
     int c,d;
     glColor4f(0.81,0.71,0.51,1);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     foreach(iter,dmesh->QFaces)
     {
            dface=dmesh->getFaceX(iter);
            a=dface->getA();b=dface->getB();c=dface->getC();d=dface->getD();

            dvert=vlist->at(a);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(b);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(c);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(d);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    glColor4f(0.51,0.41,0.51,1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    foreach(iter,dmesh->TFaces)
    {
       glBegin(GL_QUADS);
           dface=dmesh->getFaceX(iter);
           a=dface->getA();b=dface->getB();c=dface->getC();d=dface->getD();

           dvert=vlist->at(a);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

           dvert=vlist->at(b);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

           dvert=vlist->at(c);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    iter=0;
    glLineWidth(3.0f);
    glColor4f(0.31,0.27,0.51,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        count=dmesh->getEListLength();
        while(iter<count)
        {
            dedge=dmesh->getEdgeX(iter);
            a=dedge->getA();b=dedge->getB();
            dvert=vlist->at(a);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(b);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
            iter++;
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    iter=0;
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1.0);
    glPointSize(3.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

        count=dmesh->getVListLength();
        while(iter<count)
        {
            dvert=dmesh->getVertX(iter);
            glColor4fv(dvert->getColorV());
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
            iter++;
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}
```

Draw method for DomainX method:(The small cube)

```
void DomainX::drawDomain()
{
    qint32 count,iter;
    MeshX *dmesh;
    VertX *dvert;
    EdgeX *dedge;
    FaceX *dface;

    QList<VertX* > *vlist;


    dmesh=this->DMesh;
    vlist=dmesh->getVList();

     iter=0;
     int a,b;
     int c,d;
     glColor4f(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.01);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     foreach(iter,dmesh->QFaces)
     {
            dface=dmesh->getFaceX(iter);
            a=dface->getA();b=dface->getB();c=dface->getC();d=dface->getD();

            dvert=vlist->at(a);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(b);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(c);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(d);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    glColor4f(0.51,0.41,0.51,0.01);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    foreach(iter,dmesh->TFaces)
    {
       glBegin(GL_QUADS);
           dface=dmesh->getFaceX(iter);
           a=dface->getA();b=dface->getB();c=dface->getC();d=dface->getD();

           dvert=vlist->at(a);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

           dvert=vlist->at(b);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

           dvert=vlist->at(c);
           glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    iter=0;
    glLineWidth(3.0f);
    glColor4f(0.71,0.27,0.51,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        count=dmesh->getEListLength();
        while(iter<count)
        {
            dedge=dmesh->getEdgeX(iter);
            a=dedge->getA();b=dedge->getB();
            dvert=vlist->at(a);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());

            dvert=vlist->at(b);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
            iter++;
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    iter=0;
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1.0);
    glPointSize(3.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

        count=dmesh->getVListLength();
        while(iter<count)
        {
            dvert=dmesh->getVertX(iter);
            glColor4f(0.3,0.7,0.6,1);
            glVertex3fv(dvert->getV());
            iter++;
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();


}
```

Comment: One thing that seems odd is that you're culling backfaces. You want to have semi-transparent sides on your cube, but you'll never see the other side of the cube if you cull those backfaces! (Or am I misunderstanding something?)

Comment: Oops, thats one more mistake. But still again there are issues with color and depth. The output looks escher art. I can't distinguish the near and far things.

Comment: This is how it looks

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/f9ipv

Answer (score 2):

1) The drawing order is the cause.

- Depth sorted drawing of faces is required (from far to near). If intersection occurs, depth sorting must be applied for each sub face defined by intersection.
  For your specific case, splitting the cube's geometry by the plane in two halves and then draw the faces in order will theoretically do the job.

  EDIT: If the cube is the only transparent object, depth sorted drawing of the cube (without splitting up the geometry) after rendering the plane works aswell.
- Another solution is fragment based depth sorting using shader techniques like depth peeling.

2) As mentioned, backfaces of a semitransparent object must be drawn with face culling off.

Comment: Oh yeah. One thing I forgot is that because you're dealing with transparency, the depth test isn't enough. What could happen is that you might draw the cube first, with transparency, then draw the plane which intersects it. At that point, depth isn't enough information, since you'd need to be able to put the plane between the cube's front and back faces. You'd still need to keep track of the color and transparency of both faces to properly blend the cube and plane. With depth testing, it just says that the front cube face is closer than the plane and doesn't bother drawing the plane.